# Problem in animation of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

i want to make an animation of UIImageView using CGAffineTransformScale and along with it animation that uiimageview should changing it origin also. so that i written following method,

-(void)imageDidMoving
{

```
imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
imageV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[self.view addSubview:imageV];
imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageV.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

imageV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"image animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.75];    
imageV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];  

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
imageV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,1.5, 1.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

but it doesn't worked. 
I am also using CGAffineTransformScale  instead of ,

```
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(70,70, 300, 600);            
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    imageView.frame = frame2;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

but it also not working?

How i scaling and changing the origin of UIImageView without using NSTimer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
imageV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"image animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.75];    
imageV.center = CGPointMake(65, 270); 
imageV.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.76, 1.24);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hardcoding is never a solution

Comment: Yes, i appreciate your suggestion.